# How do I use Kivy's urlRequest to replace some steps in the Google APIs Client Library for Python?

Tags: python, redirect, url-routing, kivy, google-api-python-client

I am trying out Google's API client library for Python.

Follwoing the [installed application example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#example), I am able to use G+ API to login users to my app in 5 steps.

However the example deal with the auth_uri call through browser and I have to copy&paste the returned code:

```
# example code:

...
# Step 1 - auth uri is composed
auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

# Step 2 - browser is called with the propper auth_uri
webbrowser.open(auth_uri) 

# Step 3 - code is copied in browser window (crtl+c)

# Step 4 - paste code into console input (ctrl+v)
auth_code = raw_input('Enter the auth code: ')

# Step 5 - exchange code for credencials; now use API
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
```

I have tried writing a script to use kivy's UrlRequest to try and fetch the code, but I have no idea what I am supposed to do to 'navigate the returned page' (deal with redirects and forms) once I get the result

How can I deal with this in Kivy with UrlRequest? Specifically, what steps do I have to take instead of steps 3 and 4, and how to do them in Python/Kivy? If it would be too long an answer, I would appreciate any pointers to helpful information.